# Bubbling (not boiling) coolant

Tags: coolant, thermostat

I have changed my car's thermostat (a month ago), and after driving for 30 minutes, the coolant starts bubbling (it doesn't seem to be boiling) because the temperature is in the norm (95 degrees Celsius, max is 120 for my car).

Can I assume that some air got into the system while changing the thermostat? And should I do something about it? Or should I wait for the air to get out of the system in that way?

Note: I don't feel any performance issues when that bubbling starts; I guess the power would decrease if it would be boiling.

Comment: A month is much more than enough time to remove air , you have another problem. Possibly boiling in poor circulation areas in the block and by the time the steam bubble gets to the radiator ,it does not seem hot enough to be boiling.

Comment: @blacksmith37 what should I do?

Comment: My problem was with iron blocks, badly fouled with rust. So maybe flushing you block and heads would help.

Answer (score 2):

Generally bubbling coolant where the temperature is not high enough for boiling indicates a leaking head gasket, a cracked block, a warped cylinder head, or something similar that allows exhaust gas to enter the cooling system.

After opening the system to change the thermostat, you should have purged air from the system using the procedure described in the service manual for your vehicle.

If there is still air in the system, it should work its way out as you're seeing it bubble out.

But if it continues then there is a problem as noted above.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. What do you think how long (a time period, or distance to be driven) would it take for the air to get out of the system? I mean if assume there is no problem with the head gasket etc.?

Comment: It is better not to drive your car with the air trapped in the system because air means lack of coolant and lack of coolant means localized hot spots in the system which is not good.

Comment: Is there an easy way to identify if the head gasket has cracks? Without disassembling the motor head.

Comment: Sniff the bubbling gas from the coolant.  If it's exhaust gas it will smell like it.  But if this bubbling continues after purging the system there is clearly an engine problem.

Comment: It smells like pure coolant

Comment: So if it's continuing, and it sounds like it is, then there is an air leak where outside air is being drawn into the system on the suction side of the water pump.  Since you had the thermostat housing open, I'd start checking there.  Also check any hoses you had to remove.

Comment: @tmyn - You can also use a head gasket or block tester kit. It consists of a tube containing a fluid. You should install the tube on the radiator (in place of radiator cap) and run the engine. The engine should be at least warm (if not hot). If there is CO2 (combustion gases) in your cooling system, the fluid inside the tube will turn yellow.

Comment: Thank you so much, people. All the comments were really helpful. I really appreciate that. I will try to check the connections of hoses once more and then try to run the test of exhaust gases leak.

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't bleed the system properly. First of all, let the engine cool down completely. Then, open all bleeding screws and add coolant to the system until clear coolant without bubble comes out of all bleeding holes. Tighten all the screws in the order of lowest to the highest because air exits through the highest point in the cooling system.

After doing this, remove radiator cap (or reservoir tank cap) and put a relatively big funnel in the radiator filler neck. Pour coolant into the funnel so that the coolant in the funnel becomes the highest point in your cooling system.

The final step is to start the engine, keep a steady 1500 RPM and turn your heater on (because coolant should circulate through the heater core too). Let the engine run until it gets up to its normal operating temperature. You will see lots of bubbles coming out of the funnel during the process. Let cooling fans turn on and off at least 2 or 3 times. When you didn't see any bubbles, you can turn off the engine and adjust your coolant level on the reservoir when the engine is cold.
If you still see bubbling after bleeding, you may have a leakage somewhere or a problem with your cylinder head or block.